# Datastore is not a contructor error when trying ./bin/www

Tags: node.js

I received an error when I try to execute the command "./bin/www" in my installed ubuntu application on Windows.

Error is as below:

```
/mnt/c/Users/admin/Documents/html/developer_portal/app.js:91
  dataset: new Datastore(datastoreOptions)
           ^

TypeError: Datastore is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/admin/Documents/html/developer_portal/app.js:91:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/admin/Documents/html/developer_portal/bin/www:7:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
```

Comment: Please provide more info like code you tried to execute, code related to error message.

Comment: I tried to execute this in my project folder................

./bin/www

Comment: after executing the code then i get this error

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue trying to re-use some older code with v3.0 of the node helper library for Datastore.  It looks like the [import syntax has changed](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/issues/260) a bit in v3.  Line 91 in your `app.js` probably looks something like:

```
const datastore = new Datastore({projectID: 'myProject'});
```

Just before that you probably declare `Datastore` like:

```
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
```

... when what you now want is:

```
const {Datastore} = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
```